# Is EF really slow, or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to EF and I'm trying some very basic stuff.  On a brand new console application project, I just used the "Reverse Engineer Code First" (from the Entity Framework Power Tools) on a db (local to my machine.)

I then modified Main to do some basic tests...read in the same three rows from one table twice...once using EF, and once using the traditional system (SqlConnection, DataReader, etc.)  I timed both systems, and print the output times in microseconds.

When it runs I get the following (with slight variations, of course):

```
EF query 1: 5540 (slow, but startup...perhaps expected.)
EF query 2: 907 (What?  Why so slow?)
EF query 3: 910 
Trad query 1: 0 (Fast, even though I'm creating a new connection each time)
Trad query 2: 0
Trad query 3: 0
```

Am I doing something horribly wrong?  Is my LINQ query messed up and hopelessly inefficient in some way, or is EF really this slow for some reason?

Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        // EF Path
        // Selecting three rows, one at a time
        using (var context = new myCustomContext())
        {
            var query = from b in context.myTable
                        where b.KEY == "Key1"
                        select b;

            stopwatch.Stop();

            foreach (var returnedVal in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EF query 1: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }

            stopwatch.Restart();

            var query2 = from b in context.myTable
                         where b.KEY == "Key2"
                         select b;

            foreach (var returnedVal in query2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EF query 2: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }

            stopwatch.Restart();

            var query3 = from b in context.myTable
                         where b.KEY == "Key3"
                         select b;

            foreach (var returnedVal in query3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EF query 3: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
        }

        // Traditional path
        // Selecting same three rows, one at a time.  I recreate a connection
        // each time, in a futile attempt to even the odds.
        string connectionString = "<myConnectionString>";

        stopwatch.Restart();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from myTable where KEY = 'Key1'", con))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Trad query 1: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }
            }
        }

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            stopwatch.Restart();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from myTable where KEY = 'Key2'", con))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Trad query 2: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }
            }

            stopwatch.Restart();
        }

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from myTable where KEY = 'Key3'", con))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Trad query 3: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: EF is notorious with this kind of overhead. You might look into Dapper if you need better performance.

Comment: To test just the LINQ to EF generation performance without any object/graph construction, use `if (query.Any()) { .. })` - since the standard non-EF query takes "0ms" then it can be reasoned that even a SQL conversion using `EXISTS` cannot be faster/slower. Also, thanks to Connection Pooling, you're not necessarily creating a *new* connection.